# Sorting tables in an Access 2003 database with linked tables to SQL 2008 is casing locking issues

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

We are experiencing an issue where a user is doing a sort on a large table in Access 2003 with linked tables to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database is locking the entire table preventing others from doing any writes.

Is this expected behavior or is there a way to change the locking functionality for this type of operation in Access or SQL 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Create a "Snapshot" (read-only) query of the table using:

```
SELECT * FROM LinkedTableName
```

You can select "Snapshot" in the query properties window.

Then instruct users to open the query instead and carry out sorting on that, this should resolve the issue as with normal views of linked tables, Access has to read the entire table to work with the indexes in it's native DAO format, using "Snapshot" ignores this and just dumps a view of the data.

NOTE: I don't recommend using linked tables with DB's outside of Access due to these very errors, you are better on the whole using ADO connections to your SQL server as this way all the work is done server side and should avoid locking issues.

Alternatively, you could create a "pass-through" query to your SQL server, this would allow sorting without locking as this also does the work on the server side : )

Comment: Thanks for the great information. We haven't had a chance to see if this resolves our issue however it looks good.